# Is there a way to view the CreatedByID, from a Report Server database, in plaintext?

Tags: reporting-services

Title says it all really.

In the Report Server database, from the Catalog table there is a column for CreatedByID which is currently in an unreadable format.
Is there a way to convert this data or an alternative way to list all of the reports and who they were created by?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join to the users table

The following will give you a start point. Note that this filters to Type = 2 so it excludes folders and datasets etc...

```
SELECT 
        c.[Path], c.Name, u.UserName
    FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] c 
        JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] u on c.CreatedByID = u.UserID 
    WHERE c.[Type] = 2
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!